# WinAPI making a window fullscreen / borderless from another Unity program using .net 2.0

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, winapi

I have a program made in Unity that starts and stops games. (Its a launcher for an arcade machine).

I am already using winAPI to do various things. Some games cannot be set to run in fullscreen when they load, so I am trying to set it myself from my program using winAPI

I have copy & pasted various examples from the net and ended up with this.. It seems in order to do what I want to do I must 1st call SetWindowLong and then SetWindowPos.

SetWindowPos seems to be working when I call it by itself (the window gets bigger, though not quite fullscreen) But SetWindowLong does not seem to be working at all. It makes the window go crazy (it just becomes a big black square with a white square inside, and the icon for the game window in taskbar disappears)

Also I have seen similar examples of this question here. But I think my case is different. I have noticed other answers using the "Form" class which I don't think I have access to from my Unity program using .net 2.0 compatibility level.

Any ideas what is wrong with how I am calling SetWindowLong, and just my general approach?

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using UnityEngine;

public static class SetWindowLongform 
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, uint dwNewLong);
        
    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetSystemMetrics")]
    public static extern int GetSystemMetrics(int which);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern void SetWindowPos(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr hwndInsertAfter,int X, int Y, int width, int height, uint flags);

    [Flags]
    enum WindowStyles : uint
    {
        WS_OVERLAPPED = 0x00000000,
        WS_POPUP = 0x80000000,
        WS_CHILD = 0x40000000,
        WS_MINIMIZE = 0x20000000,
        WS_VISIBLE = 0x10000000,
        WS_DISABLED = 0x08000000,
        WS_CLIPSIBLINGS = 0x04000000,
        WS_CLIPCHILDREN = 0x02000000,
        WS_MAXIMIZE = 0x01000000,
        WS_BORDER = 0x00800000,
        WS_DLGFRAME = 0x00400000,
        WS_VSCROLL = 0x00200000,
        WS_HSCROLL = 0x00100000,
        WS_SYSMENU = 0x00080000,
        WS_THICKFRAME = 0x00040000,
        WS_GROUP = 0x00020000,
        WS_TABSTOP = 0x00010000,

        WS_MINIMIZEBOX = 0x00020000,
        WS_MAXIMIZEBOX = 0x00010000,

        WS_CAPTION = WS_BORDER | WS_DLGFRAME,
        WS_TILED = WS_OVERLAPPED,
        WS_ICONIC = WS_MINIMIZE,
        WS_SIZEBOX = WS_THICKFRAME,
        WS_TILEDWINDOW = WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,

        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW = WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_THICKFRAME | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX,
        WS_POPUPWINDOW = WS_POPUP | WS_BORDER | WS_SYSMENU,
        WS_CHILDWINDOW = WS_CHILD,
    }

    enum WindowLongFlags : int
    {
        GWL_EXSTYLE = -20,
        GWLP_HINSTANCE = -6,
        GWLP_HWNDPARENT = -8,
        GWL_ID = -12,
        GWL_STYLE = -16,
        GWL_USERDATA = -21,
        GWL_WNDPROC = -4,
        DWLP_USER = 0x8,
        DWLP_MSGRESULT = 0x0,
        DWLP_DLGPROC = 0x4
    }
    
    private const int SM_CXSCREEN = 0;
    private const int SM_CYSCREEN = 1;
    private static IntPtr HWND_TOP = IntPtr.Zero;
    private const int SWP_SHOWWINDOW = 64; // 0x0040
    private const uint SWP_FRAMECHANGED = 0x0020;

    public static void SetWindowFullscreenAndBorderless(IntPtr hWnd)
    {
        SetBorderless(hWnd);
        SetWinFullScreen(hWnd);
    }

    static int ScreenX
    {
        get { return GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN); }
    }

    static int ScreenY
    {
        get { return GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN); }
    }

    static void SetBorderless(IntPtr hWnd)
    {
        SetWindowLong(hWnd,(int)WindowLongFlags.GWL_STYLE,(uint)WindowStyles.WS_OVERLAPPED);
    }   

    static void SetWinFullScreen(IntPtr hWnd)
    {
        SetWindowPos(hwnd, HWND_TOP, 0, 0, ScreenX, ScreenY, SWP_FRAMECHANGED);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does Raymond Chen 's blog [How do I switch a window between normal and fullscreen?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100412-00/?p=14353) work for you?

Comment: For composition enabled(`DwmIsCompositionEnabled`), a borderless window style may be `WS_POPUP | WS_THICKFRAME | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX | WS_MINIMIZEBOX`. see the [BorderlessWindow](https://github.com/melak47/BorderlessWindow/blob/3b6978d88c0eef47f79c0ac125ec154bf701375c/BorderlessWindow/src/BorderlessWindow.cpp#L122) sample.

Comment: @YangXiaoPo-MSFT  Those examples are both C++ .. Its a lot easier to use winAPI C++ library from C++ ... Replicating that behaviour from C# is not trivial.